# Avoid include duplication in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, repository

I have two methods with same include part(these methods only for describe problem)

```
    public Car GetCarByChildEntityId(long id)
    {
        var query = DataContext.AsQueryableFor<RTraining>()
            .Where(rb => rb.Id == id)
            .Include(rb => rb.Car.CarStatus)
            .Include(rb => rb.Car.item.Customer)
            .Include(rb => rb.Car.item.MyItem.Wheel.Customer);

        return executeQuery(query).SingleOrDefault().Car;

    }


    public IEnumerable<IEntity> GetEntities()
    {
        var query = DataContext.AsQueryableFor<RTraining>()
            .Include(rb => rb.Car.CarStatus)
            .Include(rb => rb.Car.Item.Customer)
            .Include(rb => rb.Car.Item.MyItem.Wheel.Customer);

        return executeQuery(query);
    }
```

How can these three includes make common to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Develop a method like :

```
private IQueryable<Car> getCommonQuery()
{
            DataContext.AsQueryableFor<RTraining>()
            .Include(rb => rb.Car.CarStatus)
            .Include(rb => rb.Car.Item.Customer)
            .Include(rb => rb.Car.Item.MyItem.Wheel.Customer);
}

public Car GetCarByChildEntityId(long id)
{
     return executeQuery(getCommonQuery()).SingleOrDefault(rb => rb.Id == id).Car;
}

public IEnumerable<IEntity> GetEntities()
{
     return executeQuery(getCommonQuery()).OfType<IEntity>();
}
```

Note : I've no knowledge about executeQuery method, But I think my code will works, juts to be sure after that use Entity Framework profiler or SQL profiler to be sure everything is ok

Good luck